# cmake pass libray with namespace down to subdirectory

Tags: c++, cmake

Is it possible to pass a build library down to a target build in a subdirectory?

I tried something like this but i did not work

parent cmake file

```
add_library(test test.cpp)
# need something like export(test as sub::test)
add_subdirectory(main)
```

sub cmake file

```
find_package(sub::test)
add_executable(executable sub.cpp)

target_link_libraries(executable sub::test)
```

Answer (score 3):

For assign a new name to the existing target (library or executable), CMake provides [ALIAS targets](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#alias-targets). For create ALIAS for the library, use [add_library(ALIAS)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#alias-libraries) command flow:

```
# Parent CMakeLists.txt

add_library(test test.cpp)
add_library(sub::test ALIAS test)
add_subdirectory(main)
```

```
# main/CMakeLists.txt

add_executable(executable sub.cpp)

target_link_libraries(executable sub::test)
```

---

In CMake ALIAS targets are treated as **read-only** copy of the original target. E.g. one cannot add source file for the library via its alias name.

Answer (score 0):

In reply to your question:

> Is it possible to pass a build library down to a target build in a subdirectory?

Yes, it is. It even works without `find_package`.

There are only minor issues with the CMake code you posted. Let's take a look at a minimal working version.

CMakeLists.txt in parent directory:

```
# "test" is a reserved name in CMake and will cause an error, hence "testlib"
add_library(testlib test.cpp)
# relative path to header files so other targets can easily find them,
# assuming "include" but it could also be "."
target_include_directories(testlib PUBLIC include)

add_subdirectory(main)
```

CMakeLists.txt in subdirectory main:

```
add_executable(executable sub.cpp)
target_link_libraries(executable testlib)
```

In addition to that, and purely optional, you can define an *alias target* as presented by @Tsyvarev. This is recommended as a best practice in [Modern CMake](https://cliutils.gitlab.io/modern-cmake/chapters/intro/dodonot.html). It makes the differences between a library in the own project by `add_library` and one imported by `find_package` transparent.

Adding the alias target, your CMakeLists.txt's would look as follows:

```
add_library(testlib test.cpp)
target_include_directories(testlib PUBLIC include)
# Using "Parent" as a pseudo-module name. CMake module names start with a capital letter by convention.
add_library(Parent::testlib ALIAS testlib)

add_subdirectory(main)
```

and:

```
add_executable(executable sub.cpp)
target_link_libraries(executable Parent::testlib)
```